# Angular controller not talking to view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-controller

`index.html` is not working with the embedded Angular code. The link tags look like they're working (the page is formatted) -I moved the scripts tags to the top but the view still shows Angular expression syntax rather than values
`{{ products.price | currency }} instead of $18.99`

mainController looks like this:

```
app.controller('MainController',[$scope function($scope){
    //     var vm = this;
         $scope.title   = 'Bonisecrest';
         $scope.promo   = 'Season Sale';
         $scope.products = 
             [
                {
                  name: 'AHA/BHA EXFOLIATING CLEANSER',
                  price: 18.99,
                  info:  '5 fluid ounces | 148 mL',
                  image: '\images\abaBha.jpg',
                  description: "This.."
               }
}]);
```

View looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="/js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>HEADER HERE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">

        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ promo }}</h2>


        <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6"> 
          <div class="thumbnail"> 
            <img ng-src="{{products.image}}"> 
            <p class="title">{{ products.name }}</p> 
            <p class="price">{{ products.price | currency }}</p> 
            <p class="info">{{ products.info }}</p> 
          </div> 
        </div>
```

And the loaded page looks: broken.

I've tried using MainController as main:

```
 <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController as main">
      <div class="container">

        <h1>{{ main.title }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ main.promo }}</h2>
```

Also, tried without using `$scope`

```
app.controller('MainController',[function(){
         var vm = this;
         vm.title   = 'Bonisecrest';
         vm.promo   = 'Season Sale';
         vm.products =
```

I'm not sure how to check if it's the binding or the app hasn't initialized properly, or both.

Can someone spot what's wrong or missing, please?

Comment: Is there any error in console??? correct the part in line one to `['$scope',  function($scope){`

Comment: That did it! the JS files weren't loading. Console was logging: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND because of the '/' in-front of the folder path.  Fixed paths:   '<!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/p1wvsy4w/
You have to update code as follows

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope', function($scope){
app.controller('MainController',['$scope', function($scope){
//     var vm = this;
     $scope.title   = 'Bonisecrest';
     $scope.promo   = 'Season Sale';
     $scope.products = 
         [
            {
              name: 'AHA/BHA EXFOLIATING CLEANSER',
              price: 18.99,
              info:  '5 fluid ounces | 148 mL',
              image: '\images\abaBha.jpg',
              description: "This.."
           }];
   }]);
```

html

```
  <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6"> 
      <div class="thumbnail"> 
        <img ng-src="{{product.image}}"> 
        <p class="title">{{ product.name }}</p> 
        <p class="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</p> 
        <p class="info">{{ product.info }}</p> 
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Thanks for that. I made the change to the scope variable and the products array was properly closed, I just didn't paste the entire array in my question so may have accidentally left off that last bracket and semicolon. Also, fixed the html to reflect what you spotted - I can see it working fine in JSFiddle but still not in Chrome or Firefox. I tried a different CDN link for Angular thinking maybe that was the issue but still no luck.

Comment: The JS files weren't loading either. Console was logging: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND because of the '/' in-front of the folder path. Fixed paths: '<!-- Modules --> <script src="js/app.js"></script> <!-- Controllers --> <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>'   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need your first line to pass `$scope` as a string in the array and you need a comma, like this: `app.controller('MainController',['$scope', function($scope){`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20342/)

products array is not closed:

```
$scope.products = 
         [
            {
              name: 'AHA/BHA EXFOLIATING CLEANSER',
              price: 18.99,
              info:  '5 fluid ounces | 148 mL',
              image: '\images\abaBha.jpg',
              description: "This.."
           }];
```

And in template parse product rather than products:

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6"> 
      <div class="thumbnail"> 
        <img ng-src="{{product.image}}"> 
        <p class="title">{{ product.name }}</p> 
        <p class="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</p> 
        <p class="info">{{ product.info }}</p> 
      </div> 
    </div>
```